# Facebook messenger bot cannot reply automatically to any other Facebook users instead of the admin

Tags: laravel, botman

I have created a Facebook messenger chatbot, and is working perfectly with the admin, I mean the admin can interact with it without any issue, but all other users from Facebook can send it messages and the chatbot cannot respond to them automatically

Answer (score 1):

You need to go through the app approval process.

Bots can no longer work without approval from Facebook.

You need to request specifically: `pages_messaging` and `pages_messaging_subscriptions`.

Good luck.

Comment: Excuse Sir, I went into the Facebook developers, in the App and then in the App review then in the request, now am lost at that level, could you tell me all the process Please?